# Create a JSON object from HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-parsing, scrape

### Problem Overview

Let's say I have a shipment of candy.  The shipment has a number of boxes, and each box has a number of unique candy types.  Every box has a unique id, different from every other box; the same is true for candy types.  Furthermore, a candy has additional traits, like color, flavor and quantity.

### Example Code

Take the following HTML example:

```
<div class="shipment">
    <div class="box" data-boxid="a">
        <div class="candy" data-candyid="1" data-color="orange" data-flavor="orange" data-qty="7">
            <!-- unimportant content -->
        </div>
        <div class="candy" data-candyid="2" data-color="red" data-flavor="strawberry" data-qty="4">
            <!-- unimportant content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" data-boxid="b">
        <div class="candy" data-candyid="3" data-color="green" data-flavor="lime">
            <!-- unimportant content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Previous Attempts

I've seen similar examples of table parsing with jQuery's `.map()` function, and I've also seen mention of `.each()`, but I've been unable to generate any working code.

### Desired Output

I want to generate (with jQuery) a JSON object *similar* to the following:

```
{
    "shipment": {
        "a": {
            "1": {
                "color": "orange",
                "flavor": "orange",
                "qty": "7"
            },
            "2": {
                "color": "red",
                "flavor": "strawberry",
                "qty": "4"
            }
        },
        "b": {
            "3": {
                "color": "green",
                "flavor": "lime"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Additional Notes

**My app already uses jQuery extensively, so it seems like a logical tool for the job.**  However, if plain 'ol JavaScript is a more appropriate choice, feel free to say so.

The HTML is always going to be well-formed and always going to follow a the format specified.  However, in some cases, information may be incomplete.  **Note that the third candy had no quantity specified, so quantity was simply ignored while building the object.**

Comment: A combination of `.each()` and `.find()` should do the trick. Start at the top and work your way to the inner properties.

Comment: I've tried something similar, but I believe I encountered working with children of children (e.g., nested `.each()` functions).  Could you please post an example?

I'm not necessarily asking for a complete solution (after all, this is a fictional example).  Just a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This generates what you asked for:

```
var json = {};   

$('.shipment').each(function(i,a) {
    json.shipment = {};

    $(a).find('.box').each(function(j,b) {
        var boxid = $(b).data('boxid');
        json.shipment[boxid] = {};

        $(b).find('.candy').each(function(k,c) {
            var $c = $(c),
                candyid = $c.data('candyid'),
                color = $c.data('color'),
                flavor = $c.data('flavor'),
                qty = $c.data('qty');
            json.shipment[boxid][candyid] = {};
            if (color) json.shipment[boxid][candyid].color = color;
            if (flavor) json.shipment[boxid][candyid].flavor = flavor;
            if (qty) json.shipment[boxid][candyid].qty = qty;
        });
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/D22mD/

As you can see, at each level it uses `.each()` to loop through the elements matching a certain class and then `.find().each()` to loop through the desired children. In between, `.data()` is used to grab the desired `data-` attributes and the json object is built level by level.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also, I appreciate the explanation of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Is this close to what you are looking for? – http://jsfiddle.net/4RPHL/

I have used `data()` and `JSON.stringify` to create the json.

Be sure to check your console where I have logged the output.

```
$(".candy").each(function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify($(this).data()))
});
```

Comment: Simple and elegant.  This seems like what I'm looking for.

How do I nest the `.each()` function so I can `.stringify` recursively?

Comment: OP specified what the desired output should look like, and this is not it.

Comment: Blazemonger: OP used keyword "similar"

Comment: It's helpful.  But I'm still not clear on how to achieve the nested structure.

Answer (score 1):

Nice problem! Thanks to Chris' post I was able to get this to work.

```
var shipments = [],
    shipment  = {},
    boxes = {},
    candy = {};
$(".shipment").each(function() {
    var shipment = {},
        boxes = {};
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        var boxdata = $(this).data();
        candy = {};
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            var candydata = $(this).data();
            candy[candydata["candyid"]] = {
                color: candydata["color"],
                flavor: candydata["flavor"],
                qty: candydata["qty"]
            };
            boxes[boxdata["boxid"]] = candy;
        });
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(boxes)); // works
    });
    shipment = {shipment: boxes};
    shipments.push(shipment); // for multiples
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(shipments[0]));
console.log(shipments.length);  // 1 for the example html above
```